# Visual C# Delegate Array

Tags: c#, arrays, static, delegates

Okay. So what I want to do... I'm trying to store a list of status effects as delegates in an array. The statuses will act like the statuses in the pokemon games.. (Stun makes you lose a turn etc).

I have this so far...

```
public class Statuses : Chara{
        public static void para(){
            this.health -= 10;
        }
    }

     status[] statuses = new status[]{
        new status(Statuses.para)
    };
```

It's complaining about this not being a static property, I was wondering how I should proceed.

Thanks heaps.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, where you're trying to declare `statuses`, what the `status` type is, or what the `Chara` type is. I would also strongly advise that you start following .NET naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler error you most likely are getting when compiling the `Statuses` class says it all: “Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer”: You are not allowed to reference “this” in a static method. If your `health` variable is static you can do like this:

```
private static int health;
public static void para() 
{
    health -= 10; 
}
```

If `health` is not static you will get this compiler error “An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Statuses.health'.

Another error is that your `para` is not a property but a method. Since the code you have posted are very out of context a number of different errors could be present at well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem the compiler is complaining about is that you've marked the method `Para` as `static`. You're then trying to access the `health` property of the current instance using `this`, which doesn't make sense, given that the containing method is `static`.

You should read up on the [static keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [its usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

---

I think what you wanted to do was to create a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) that reduces the instance's health, along the lines of (assuming you have a type called `pokemon`, with a property `health`):

```
public class Statuses : Chara{
    public static Action<Pokemon> para =
        (pokemonInstance) => { pokemonInstance.Health -= 10; };
}

Action<Pokemon>[] statuses = new Action<Pokemon>[]{
    Statuses.para
};
```

Read up on [Action<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) and [Anonymous Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx).

Comment: I know - but delegates can only be used with static methods can't they?

Comment: You can also assign a delegate, or in my case `Action<T>` in-place. In my above code i'm creating a method that has a single parameter, the `pokemonInstance`. The method will reduce the health by 10. I'm assigning that method to the `para` static variable.